# Did Lois Lowry name the protagonist of the Giver from the biblical prophet?

Tags: inspiration, name-significance, the-bible, the-giver, lois-lowry

Did Lois Lowry name Jonas, the protagonist of the Giver, after the biblical prophet Jonah? Both of them are at one point reluctant to follow their calling that they didn't choose, so there is some similarity. But I haven't seen this confirmed or denied in an interview.

Comment: [This one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonah), right?

Comment: @Randal'Thor yes, that prophet

Comment: For that matter, there's also the incident with the Apple, which might be a Biblical reference too.